Redundant latchup protection with LTC1153 circuit breaker
I've been trying to design a redundant latchup protection circuit based on the LTC1153 circuit breaker for a while, but its pin configuration is giving me a hard time. What I am trying to accomplish is:

if the load latches up and draws excessive current, one of the two LTC1153 cuts power to the load temporarily to clear the fault.
if either of the LTC1153 latches up and draws excessive current, the unaffected LTC1153 cuts power to the other temporarily to clear the fault.

I initially thought of an arrangement in which one of the LTC1153 was able to cut power to both the load and the downstream LTC1153, and the downstream LTC1153 could cut power to the upstream LTC1153 (sizing a capacitor to retain power during the auto-reset period), but I don't see that working with the chip's pin configuration for sensing.
Any ideas? I could simulate it in LTspice.

Source: LTC1153 datasheet.

I’m not sure I understand the problem. Can you draw at least the block diagram of what you have in mind? Be specific: how many mosfets? One shared or one per breaker chip? How does the sensing not work? Etc.

I wish I could (i have a soft spot for block diagrams), but I think this is the first step of the answer in that the block diagram I'd make would really be 3 boxes with question marks in between them. As long as there aren't more ICs than these two, I don't really mind adding discrètes including MOSFETs though simpler is better since we are talking of reliability.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica: the bounty is going to expire, would you be so kind as to taking a stab at it even if it's a hunch? I can't believe there is no (smart) way of doing SEL protection with commercial grade components. Thanks!

What are your voltage and load requirements? And could you elaborate more on "if either of the LTC1153 latches up and draws excessive current,..." part? Why do you think the LTC1153 would latch up and draw excessive current? It's not exactly a load. If it did latch up and draw excessive current, it would surely be damaged at that point. You really would need a fuse for that fail mode (if I'm understanding your intention correctly).

Also, are you requesting redundancy for safety? Or for reliability?

@MOSFET: basically much in the same way the LTC1153 cuts off power to the load before it destroys itself, I'd like both LTC1153 to protect eachother by cutting off power if their parasitic thyristor engages because of a latchup. Redundancy is for reliability only. The load could vary wildly since it's an external MOS and I intend to use this circuit in various locations but I'd say from 5V 1A to 12V 3A?

I don't think you understand how these devices (LTC1153) work which is why you're having trouble getting an answer. There is no parasitic thyristor to latch up - the MOSFET gate is driven by an internal charge-pump. The more common problem would be the MOSFET never turns on due to the charge pump. Further, the load CAN'T vary wildly cause the trip point is current-based. So you would have to set the trip point above worst-case (3 amps?). Depending on your load, changes in voltage may induce changes in current. This question lacks a lot of details. What is the load you are trying to protect?

@MOSFET: By "vary wildly" I mean not in time, from unit to unit. This would be used for multiple loads. I'd set the fault trip current to be twice the peak load current. I haven't looked at how the part works, but since latchups can occur for any two transistors on die that are close enough how can you be so sure that this part is inherently latchup-free? It'd be advertised as rad-tolerant, at least in radiation test reports and it never appeared in my research about this component's tolerance to radiation.


Any ideas? I could simulate it in LTspice.

I would probably use a cheap micro to do the job of the LTC1153 (unless you can't have one). I currently am doing the same thing to protect a laser diode and ended up changing the design from an analog current sensing to a micro, it actually ended up being cheaper (and you can use some ISR's that can detect latchups on a micro to ensure saftey and latchups).
Another option would be if you have a spare ADC on the project you could add in a current sense amplifier and detect the current in parallel (or without the LTC1153) You could also just use a comparator to detect and then do something with that, you could use the signal to shutdown the LTC1153 Or combine it with the output of the LTC1153 to double check it's current function.

Source: from LTC1153 datasheet
Edit:
A simpler circuit with rad hard parts might use a current mirror. Here is an example with a 1.5 and 3A pulse, you could send that into a comparator or ADC and then react to the current fault. The resistors would need to be sized differently for different FETs and I'm not sure what the load and parasitics of the circuit look like, but this gives you and idea.


Thanks for the answer (+1). I think your diagram shows a way to add redundancy for load protection but sacrifices the LTC1153 (with a fuse I assume?)? I actually do have a rad tolerant microcontroller in most places I needed this in, but I'm having issues finding current sense amplifiers that are rad tolerant and the ones I do find double the costs. First thought is to use a LTC1153 to protect them but I'd be back at square one. In a few places I resort to large wasteful sense resistors to not need to amplify, but I can't do that everywhere. Any thoughts?

Yeah, is there a possibility you could use a current mirror and then detect with that? What are the nominal and fault currents that you need to detect?
You can parallel the LTC1153 with a current mirror. If you have an issue with the LTC1153 then you can add redundancy, A better thing would be to just use the a current sense opamp, you could build one of these if you already have a cheap rad hard opamp in your design already. Do you have a way to digitally detect or use an ADC?

Pretty much any rad tolerant part including opamps is a few hundreds a pill, and this is used in identical modules throughout our design so I'm trying to find something without an additional rad-tol part unfortunately. A current mirror is a good idea, would you recommend the classic circuit? I'd say fault current should be twice peak current but I expect much more than that, similar to a short. Haven't measured it though. Bipolars degrade more than MOSFETs but since this is assuming heavy shielding it could work

Never made a current mirror with a smaller output current yet though (because I can't go much lower in Vdd)

I can look at a current mirror design, but I need to know what you can monitor the output with and the current, you want to use fets, which you already have a rad tolerant fet I would imagine. Also what is the load and the fault current?

Thanks, appreciated. I got a few spare 3.3V VREF ADC channels from the rad-tol µC (around 10pF input cap and 200Ohm series resistance, sampling rate is unimportant), I guess we can give it a shot with a typical 5V 1.5A average 2A peak load

You could use a current mirror like I posted and then run the output into an ADC.

Thanks, I've awarded the reward but I think it makes sense that I leave the question open given that the original question is on the LTC1153 specifically. I don't mind accepting the answer if you don't agree. I'll breadboard that and analyse how sensitive this is. See you around :)

It should be possible to use this schematic diagram.
U1 is the classic circuit which cuts the power supply (via the IRLR024) if the load current exceeds 1A or the load temperature exceeds 70°C. U2 is wired as a temperature sensor via the PTC. If the temperature of U1 exceeds 100°C, the MTD3055E will open.

I couldn't simulate this, so I'll let you try it and see if it works.

Thanks, but isn't the thermal action only for overload protection and not for latchup protection? I'd expect the chip would get destroyed much quicker than what the case would allow us to detect by its tempetature

@MisterMystère, Sorry, I misunderstood your question. To monitor an abnormal current during the trip delay (during latching function), it may be necessary to measure the “quiescent current ON”. It seems complicated with only 2 LT1153
